# Module Development: What fieldset name do I need to use to add JFields to the tabs: Menu Assignment & Module Permissions

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-module, module-params

What fieldset name do I need to use to add JFields to the tabs: Menu Assignment & Module Permissions

Please see below picture for more details.

[image: Picture about the tab items in question and the name field inside a editor.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you **can not** add custom fields to "Menu assignment" & "Module Permissions" tabs, because these are only for core features.

You have three options:

**Module tab**

```
<fieldset name="basic">
```

**Advanced tab**

```
<fieldset name="advanced">
```

**Custom tab**

```
<fieldset name="custom_name">
```

Custom tab is what you currently have, you just need some name for it.

Comment: Thank you I already knew about the Custom Tab been using them for years. Was just wondering if it where possible.

Comment: I figured that you knew. Just added this for anybody else who would search same thing.

Comment: Could you consider upvoting the question if you find it a clear question. You would help me considerably in gaining a little bit of reputation. Thank you and also for answering the question in June.